# comma before "with"

Tags: punctuation, absolute-constructions

The following text is a partial transcription of Steve Jobs’s June 6 keynote address at the 2011 Apple Worldwide Developer’s Conference (WWDC), with a specific focus on Jobs’s remarks on the iCloud.

> Because all these new devices have communications built into them. They can all talk to the cloud whenever they want. And so now, if I get something on my iPhone it’s sent up to the cloud immediately. Let’s say I take some pictures with it, those pictures are in the cloud, and they are now pushed down to my devices completely automatically. **And now everything’s in sync with me not even having to think about it.** I don’t even have to take the devices out of my pocket. I don’t have to be near my Mac or PC.

In the emboldened sentence, is it correct to not have a comma before *with me not even having to think about it*?

If so, would it be wrong to add a comma there?

> And now everything’s in sync, with me not even having to think about it.

Comment: The quote is a good example of *“There are no rules in English, only guidance. Some guidance looks like a rule; it probably isn't."* ++ The answer depends on Steve Job’s exact intonation – when he was speaking, did he pause after the word “sync”? If you do not know the answer to this, then the answer to your question is “We do not know whether (a) there should be no punctuation (b) there should be a comma (c) there should be some other punctuation mark.

Comment: @Greybeard Does that mean if you're writing the sentence from scratch that it doesn't matter whether you use a comma there or not?

Comment: It should have a comma, to avoid the misreading “in sync with.”

Comment: @listeneva No, of course not. When producing a transcript or simply writing, the aim is to communicate the meaning as accurately as possible: punctuation (and no punctuation) helps in this.

Comment: @Xanne I think that is unlikely.

Comment: @Greybeard When simply writing, how do you determine if there's a "pause" or not?

Comment: @listeneva You will have to accept that, without hearing what was said, and thus **how** it was said, there is no definitive answer.

Comment: @Greybeard It's not about me accepting anything. It's about you explaining to me how a "pause" in speaking should be able to affect when you're writing from scratch, when there's no pause in writing.

Comment: It would be the shortest garden path mislead ever, and the 'rule' (codified in Grice's maxims) 'avoid ambiguity / difficulty of reading (both senses)', one of the best in English, is, as @Greybeard implies, disregardable in this case. The comma is inherently optional, and should be used to show how it is wished the sentence be read out. If the sentence is a quote, the reporter should check the source, or if original, make their own choice on the day.

Comment: @listeneva I do not see any request for an explanation of the use of *pauses in general/in all circumstances* in your question. Your example is specifically about a particular transcript. Punctuation, in the accurate reproduction of a transcript, will also attempt to faithfully reproduce speech patterns. The absence of a comma ***should*** therefore mean that there was no pause.

Comment: @Greybeard That's incorrectly assuming that a pause is the only factor in determining whether to put a comma there.

Comment: @listeneva If the meaning is that *everything is in sync (with me)*, then use a comma. If the meaning is that *everything is sync with me*, then don't use a comma. Is what follows *in sync* extraneous, additional information, or is it integral to the sentence itself? The discussion of there having been a pause in the speech is mostly irrelevant when it comes to restrictive versus nonrestrictive information. A pause may or may not occur at the same time, but that doesn't mean a strict 1–1 correspondence with a written comma. As a transcript, it's ambiguous which meaning was intended.